# Can data files (i.e. PDF, CSV, etc) be copied to Xcode Preview?

Tags: xcode, preview

Recently I had to search for how to copy data files (i.e. PDF, CSV, etc.) into my Xcode simulator for debugging sessions.

While I realize that Xcode **Preview** has a lot of limitations, I was curios if the same could be done to use external files like that in **Previews**?

For instance I have a SwiftUI view that calls uses

```
.fileImporter(
            isPresented: $isShowingDocumentPicker,
            allowedContentTypes: [.spreadsheet, .commaSeparatedText]) { newValue in
            }
```

It would be great if I could somehow place test files in a location that the **Preview** would access so I don't have to go to the debugger instead.